# trouble building boost unit test with gcc 4.4.x

Tags: c++, boost

Here i tried to create boost unit test without , linking using the
unit_test_framework.hpp.(it works)

xRunner.cpp

```
// Works Fine
#define BOOST_AUTO_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test_framework.hpp>

xMain.cpp
// Works Fine
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( COntroller )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( tc1 )
{
       BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(2+2, 3);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Even if xMain.cpp is changed to

```
// Works Fine 
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>


namespace Xmp{

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( tc1 )
{
       BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(2+2, 3);
}

}
```

Above all works, when i complie like
g++ -I/root/raju/../../boost/ -o xOut xRunner.cpp xMain.cpp

---

But, When i try to compile the same program's xMain.cpp, xRunner.cpp under.
Gcc= 4.4.1, with the same "-I/root/raju/../../boost/"
I get the follwoing error.

Test.cpp:8: undefined reference to
`boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::set_checkpoint(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char
const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
/usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework.so: undefined reference to`
init_unit_test_suite(int, char**)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

ll /usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 May 28  2013
/usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework.so ->
libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.33.1

g++ version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

---

Any pointer , to resolve above linking issue woudl be great.
(I tried even boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>)